# datetime.strptime is not support to convert future date?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I had the following error in Nov 13th 2022

```
end = datetime.strptime("2022-11-16", "%Y-%d-%m")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 6
```

but I didn't have the error in the following case,

```
date_value = datetime.strptime("2022-11-12", "%Y-%d-%m")
```

Well, strptime function of datetime module is not support to convert for future date?
If no, let me know the way....please

Answer (score 1):

Future dates are supported by datetime.strptime. Here, you're trying to convert a date with 16 months which is leading to the error. I'm guessing you're looking for

```
datetime.strptime("2022-11-16", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.strptime("2022-11-16", "%Y-%d-%m")
```

That format string is year-day-month, but you're passing a date string of year-month-day.  So it tried to interpret 16 as the month.

Your second example happened to work because it had 12 for the month.

Answer (score 0):

Datetime strptime supports future date.
We only have 12 Months but you are asking for 16th Month which doesn't exist.

```
datetime.strptime("2022-16-11", "%Y-%d-%m")
```